# Passing ng-change to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

We have a directive which consists of the select element as shown below

```
<select class="form-control" ng-if="type === 'select'" name="{{ bsName }}" id="{{ bsName }}"
            ng-model="$parent.ngModel" ng-change="$parent.ngChange" ng-options="(item.label || item) for item in items" ng-selected="(item.value && $parent.ngModel == item.value) || $parent.ngModel == item">
```

and in our view we use it as below

```
<bs-input type="select" items="cars" bs-name="car" bs-label="Car" ng-model="criteria.car" bs-errors="errors" ng-change="onChange()"/>
```

But the onChange() doesn't get triggered when I am select a different value from the list. Is passing it as

```
ng-change="$parent.ngChange"
```

correct? Am I missign something?

Note: When I don't use a directive and have the select directly in my view everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `$parent.ngChange` will try to access the property ngChange on the parent scope. The `ng-change` *attribute* on the bs-input is something completely different.

What would probably work is calling `$parent.onChange()`, as you're now calling the function directly. However, I hope you see the drawback here, as we're then hardcoding the function which you want to call, which is not your intention.

Also, I'm assuming that you're using an isolate scope in the directive, in which case calling $parent makes no sense (it works, but you want the directive to be independant of parent scopes).

You can look into using $parse to get the function passed through from the outside scope.

Comment: You are right. I had to give a different property name other than ngChange..that did the trick..